# Why does the Yule-Walker equation for AR(1) only hold for $k \ge 1$?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, arima

I have a AR(1) process $X_t = 0.4X_{t-1} + Z_t$. I multiplied by $X_{t-k}$, took the expectation of both sides, divided by the variance (which I assume is stationary), and got the Yule-Walker equation:

$$\rho(k) = 0.4\rho(k-1)$$

I thought that this is true for every $k$, but I was told that this is true only for $k\ge 1$. Why is that? where did I assume that in my derivation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, for $k=0$, you'll have:
$$\begin{align}\rho(0)&=E[X_t^2]=E[(0.4X_{t-1}+Z_t)^2]=(0.4)^2\underbrace{E[X_{t-1}^2]}_{\rho(0)}+0.8\underbrace{E[X_{t-1}Z_t]}_{0}+E[Z_t^2]\\&=0.16\rho(0)+\sigma_z^2\rightarrow \rho(0)=\frac{\sigma_z^2}{1-0.16}\end{align}$$
Typical assumptions are $E[Z_t]=0$ and $E[X_{t-1}Z_t]=0$.

But, let $k\geq1$:
$$\begin{align}\rho(k)&=E[X_tX_{t-k}]=E[(0.4X_{t-1}+Z_t)X_{t-k}]=0.4E[X_{t-1}X_{t-k}]+\underbrace{E[X_{t-k}Z_t]}_{0}\\&=0.4\rho(k-1)\end{align}$$

You can't assume $E[X_{t-k}Z_t]=0$ when $k=0$ because $$E[X_tZ_t]=0.4\underbrace{E[X_{t-1}Z_t]}_{0}+E[Z_t^2]=\sigma_z^2$$
You can only assume the independence of current output and the future input; not current input and the current output.

Note: for all $k$, we have $\rho(k)=\rho(-k)$ so you don't need to consider $k\leq -1$ separately.

Comment: isn't it (1-0.16) in the denominator?

Comment: so you mean that it's true for every $k\neq0$

Comment: Oh right, I've corrected the denominator, not the exact relation, $\rho$ is symmetric around $0$. For example: $\rho(2)=0.4\rho(1)\rightarrow \rho(-2)=0.4\rho(-1)$

Comment: so it's not true for k < 0! there it's $\rho(k) = 0.4\rho(k+1)$ - why is that? where in your derivation did you assume that k>=1 and not simply $k\neq0$?

Comment: ah :) because if k < 0, then $E(X_{t-1}X_{t-k}) = \rho(k+1)$. sorry for bothering you and thanks

Comment: also note that you used $\rho(0)=E(X_t^2)$ (auto-corel) where strictly speaking it's  $\lambda(0)=E(X_t^2)$ (auto-covariance), also in all other references to auto-corel in your answer it should have been auto-covariance. Also, note that you're assuming everywhere stationarity ($E(X_t)=0$), otherwise $\lambda(0)=E(X_t^2) - E(X_t)^2$

Comment: Right, the nomenclature for auto-correlation is not stable across disciplines: see here: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Autocorrelation#/Normalization ; in my answer, $\rho$ denotes the auto-covariance function, but simple scaling with $\lambda(0) $yields the autocorrelation function. So, the relation still holds. Mean of $X_t$ will be $0$ when mean of $Z_t$ is $0$; which typically is, since $Z$ is modelled as a noise process.